# Incompatible Pointer Type Eclipse Function

Tags: c, eclipse, function, pointers, arguments

I have a function which is performing some read operation from Sockets using udp,

the function is like this

```
  int Read_packet(int CSPL_Socket, void *buf,int datalen)
{
    int numb_bytes=0;
    numb_bytes=read(CSPL_Socket, buf, datalen);
                        if(numb_bytes<0)
                        {
                            CSPL_SOK_ERROR(-6);
                            close(CSPL_Socket);
                            exit(1);
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //printf("Count %d\n",numb_bytes);
                        }
    return 0;
}
```

When i call this from Eclipse ide, it shows a warning as shown below

[image]

But i dont see any performance issues here , everything is working good, how can i remove this warning ?

This is my definition for pkt

```
    typedef struct UDP_Packet {
    unsigned short Year;          // year
    unsigned char  Month;         // months
    unsigned char  Day;           // day
    unsigned char  Hour;          // hour
    unsigned char  Minute;        // minute
    unsigned char  Seconds;       // seconds
    unsigned short Milliseconds;  // milliseconds
    unsigned char  SeqNo;         // packet sequence no
    unsigned short CommandCode;   // packet type
    unsigned char  DestSubSysID;  // Destination sub system id (0 to 255)
    unsigned char  DestNodeID;    // Destination node id
    unsigned char  SrcSubSysID;   // Source sub system id
    unsigned char  SrcNodeID;     // Source node id
    unsigned short DataSize;      // Data size in bytes
    unsigned char  AckSel;        // select acknowledgment option
    unsigned char  AckID;         // ID for ACK
    unsigned char  DataFlag;      // Flag indicating single part(0) or multipart data (1)
    unsigned char  MessageID;     // unique message ID
} UDP_Packet;    

 UDP_Packet pkt;
```

Comment: That's an odd warning: Usually, a function that has a `void*` parameter can take (almost) any type of pointer. How have you declared `pkt`? Does it have a `const` qualifier? Or is it a pointer-to-pointer?

Comment: @Adrian Mole i have edited question and added the definition for packet

Comment: The warning is not generated by Eclipse, but by the compiler. Did you compile it accidently as C++ code, not as C code?

Comment: @the busybee no my ide perspective is in C itself

Comment: The perspective is not the point and does not decide _the language_. When you build, Eclipse shows you in the Console view what commands are called and their output. Please open this view and copy its contents into your question. You might need to clean the build before to trigger a full rebuild.